# Which timezone should I imply in my web service interface?

Tags: web-services, datetime, time, utc

I'm implementing a REST web service that will be used from all around the world. The service will accept "date and time" datatype parameters and serve results also containing "date and time" datatype.

The question is - which timezone do I assume "date and time" belongs to? Do I just force all users to use UTC or is there a better way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either include a Timezone property to this service allowing it to specify or assume UTC.